# Update inner Dictionary as Value in outer Dictionary

Tags: c#, collections, .net-4.0, dictionary, foreach

In such a construction:

```
Dictionary<myObject, Dictionary<myEnum, secondObject>> myDict;
```

I use `foreach` to search all items in outer `Dictionary`:

```
foreach (var elem in myDict)
{
//I need to make some modifications in inner Dictionary for chosen myEnum
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` loop on a `Dictionary` enumerates key-value pairs. The key is in `elem.Key`; the value (i.e. your target inner dictionary) is `elem.Value`.

```
foreach (var elem in myDict)
{
    //I need to make some modifications in inner Dictionary for chosen myEnum
    Dictionary<myEnum, secondObject> inner = elem.Value;
    inner[myEnum.EnumVal1] = new secondObject(123);
    inner[myEnum.EnumVal2] = new secondObject(456);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, it seems you just have some confusion over getting access to the inner dictionary?

```
foreach (var elem in myDict) // var is KeyValuePair<myObject, Dictionary<myEnum, secondObject>>
{
    var innerDict = elem.Value; // Value is Dictionary<myEnum, secondObject>

    if (innerDict != null)
    {
        if (innerDict.ContainsKey(enumVal)) // key is myEnum
        {
            var value = innerDict[enumVal]; // var is secondObject
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no details is given about myObject or secondObject the following may be too generic but at least may give you an idea:

```
foreach (var elem in myDict)
{
    var temp = elem.Value.Single(p => p.Key == MyEnum.a);
    (temp.Value as MySecondObject).anyProperty = anyValue;
}
```